# RxView clicks and onError

Tags: rx-java, rx-binding

Using RxView to handle the clicks I have to implement the onError. I understand that the onError is always there in observers but is there a case when the RxView.clicks(myview) will actually call onError?

```
    RxView.clicks(buttonView).ignoreElements().subscribeWith(new DisposableCompletableObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(@io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull Throwable e) {
            // when would this be called?
        }

    });
```

Is it a good pattern to define a class that implements an empty onError assuming that it will never be called? I did not find anything stating that this is true but I can't think about a case when the onError will actually be called

Answer (score 0):

I ended doing this:

```
RxView.clicks(buttonView).ignoreElements().subscribeWith(aVoid -> {});
```

So here I'm passing a `Consumer` instead of an `Observer`. This of course means that I'm assuming I do not need to handle the error.